# SQL Server : join on both indexed view and original table in same query

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server table called `dbo.Documents` which has an index and primary key on the column `primary_id`. I also have an indexed view on this table called `dbo.vw_Documents` which is indexed on column `secondary_id`.

I want to write a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    dbo.Document DOC
LEFT JOIN  
    dbo.PrimaryTable PRIME WITH (INDEX(IDX_Documents_primary_id))
                           ON PRIME.primary_id = DOC.primary_id
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.SecondaryTable SECND WITH (INDEX(IDX_Documents_secondary_id))
                             ON SECND.secondary_id = DOC.seconary_id
```

Basically, I want to join `dbo.Documents` to `dbo.PrimaryTable` and `dbo.SecondaryTable` using different indexes for both.

How can I achieve this with an indexed view?

I tried just specifying the different index, but it doesn't work, and the secondary index is ignored.

Comment: Why are you forcing index through hints? Can you paste the plan for us to see? Perhaps your indexes aren't being used since they aren't covering. Please use the following tool to share your plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: This is a bit open ended.  You should first look at the query plan and try to understand the physics of what the optimizer is actually doing.  Most of the time, index hints are not needed, and I would say that having two hints in one query has a bad smell.

Comment: I would paste the query plan, but it's larger than this question implies. Basically, it's not using an index where I want it to and I believe it's because SQL can't use the indexed view and the regular table at the same time. That is to say, it can't use both the primary_id and the secondary_id in the same query automatically. That's my guess anyway.

Comment: Is the query plan larger because you are actually using a larger query than the one in your question?   If so, that could be the actual cause, and not what you think.  What happens if you look at the query plan of the actual query you have posted (no other joins or filters)?   Isolate, isolate, isolate!

Comment: I see in the query plan that 76% of the time is spent joining on dbo.SecondaryTable with the primary_id. That's incorrect. That's without the hints.